# What is a vector autoregressive model?

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression

I'm looking to understand this from a managerial perspective. For example if I was explaining linear regression I would say it is a line of best fit through some data points and it can be used to predict a "y" value for some given value of "x". Is there an analogous explanation for VAR? I do not have a strong background in statistics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If purely from managerial perspective, VAR is practically the same as linear regression. The main difference is that in VAR you have several dependent variables instead of one. This means that instead of one linear regression you have several. Your interpretation of linear regression remains valid, since each VAR regression is usually estimated using OLS.

As in linear regression so in VAR there exists various things you can or cannot do or should beware of. But these would be best explained if you provided more precise question.

Comment: I might add that VARs are for multivariate time series data, and that each outcome is modeled using previous values of itself as well as other lagged outcome variables (that's the autoregressive part).

Answer (score -6):

In Var models instead of using several dependent variable we use several independent variable and their effect on one dependent variable.

Comment: You seem to have mixed up "dependent" and "independent" in this answer, which causes it to contradict the older (and correct one).